# Running C# Code on Linux Ubuntu (Visual Studio 2019)

Tags: c#, linux, cmd, virtual-machine, visual-studio-2019

I wrote a simple code with C# in Visual Studio, which opens cmd and then types in the command 'dir'
the code is this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo myProcess = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
            myProcess.Arguments = @"/c dir C:\Users\Test\Desktop";
            Process.Start(myProcess);
```

It works fine on windwos
but I want to execute in on linux so I "convert it with the command
dotnet publish -c release -r ubuntu.20.04-x64

Not to forget I changed the code for my linux vm:

```
ProcessStartInfo myProcess = new ProcessStartInfo("/bin/bash");
            myProcess.Arguments = @"ls";
            Process.Start(myProcess);
```

Can anybody help me, that the code runs on my linux system too ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I dont know why but my greeting got cut by the editor: "So Hi everyone"

Comment: What happens why you try your modified code on Linux?

Comment: @NetMage ich gives something out with, no binary file can be excecuted

Comment: If you execute `/bin/bash ls`, it will try to find a file `ls` and parse it as a bash script. You probably want to run `/bin/bash -c ls`, but there's probably not much reason to put the bash wrapper around it, just call `/bin/ls`.